# How to pass a 3D grid of voxel into a fragment shader in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, voxel

i want to make a voxel engine in javascript using webgl api. But i don't know to send to the gpu a 3D grid of voxel. I know of work voxel engine so there is no need to give me paper about how to render voxel. I'm just asking about how to get voxel information.

Comment: volume dds texture, or as xyz buffer…

Comment: Your answer interests me, can you develop please?